# Setting up gradle and gradle plugin and dependencies in in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, plugins, dependencies

After installing arctic fox on linux, I tried to create a new project but was told there was no gradle and it wanted to download one.  Not having a great internet connection I downloaded gradle 6.9.2 and I pointed the gradle to the folder.

It's apparently not enough to just have gradle but it needs a plugin as well. Which gets specified in project structure - project.  None of the options in project structure work but manually setting version 3.5.3 in the build.gradle does.

The issue I have now is that I have no idea where the 3.5.3 comes from?  Is there a folder where all these plugins are installed where one can check what is available?

I'm having the same issue with other dependencies where just starting a new project requires that I re-download all the dependencies again despite the fact that I can open another project and it builds just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin version depend on gradle plugin. You can see version require docs from here: https://developer.android.google.cn/studio/releases/gradle-plugin
And plugin will be downloaded from google maven repository: https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.android.tools.build:gradle
You can also find them on your local maven cache directory.

Comment: How would you know where the local maven repository resides?  Ive seen articles mentioning ~/.m2 but no such directory wxists on the partition.  Is there perhaps a path variable ser somewhere?